# Good way of catching custom 'indirect' exceptions

Tags: python, exception, module

I'm developing a python application and there's a specific scenario that is causing me some confusion about handling custom exceptions defined in distinct modules. Consider the following case:

There are modules `A.py`, `B.py` and `C.py`. The `A.py` defines a custom exception and raises it in case of error. `B.py` imports `A.py` and run its dangerous functions. Later on, `C.py` will import `B.py` and execute its methods. Representation below:

**A.py** -> do simple stuff, but it's prone to raise a custom exception.

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass

def dangerous_function():
    ...
    raise CustomException('Exception occurred')
```

**B.py** -> have lots of methods that use the dangerous function from module `A`.

```
import A

class ModuleB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run_stuff(self):
        ...
        A.dangerous_function() # throws CustomException

    def run_more_stuff(self):
        ...
        A.dangerous_function() # throws CustomException
        ...

    ...
```

**C.py** -> instantiate module `B` and run its methods.

```
from A import CustomException # <--
from B import ModuleB

def do_stuff():
    m = ModuleB()

    try:
        m.run_stuff()
    except CustomException as e:
        print(f'Custom error occurred: {e}')
```

Assuming that module `A` shoudn't be visible to module `C`, is it ok to import it just to get the custom exception? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'd say the only issue is if executing the full content of `A.py` would be prohibitively expensive, in which case you might want to break out the exceptions into a separate module.

Comment: Only the first import will execute `A.py`: after that the module is cached as `sys.modules['A']` and subsequent imports just look it up there. `A` has to be loaded anyway for the exceptions to be raised. Having a separate module for the exception classes does make them easier to find, though. (See 'Organization' in Danjou's guide.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` doesn't need to know about `A`. `B` can do `from A import CustomException` and then the class will be available as `B.CustomException`. Then `C` can import it from `B`:

```py
from B import ModuleB, CustomException
```

---

If however you don't want `C` to depend on the custom exception class at all, you can make `B` catch the exceptions and raise exceptions defined by `B` instead. (You can use `raise from` to make the original exception available too for debug output.)

See the section on wrapping in https://julien.danjou.info/python-exceptions-guide/ for a bit more on this.